# why using NSArray (and other non-display graphic element) into Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, nsarray

using IB, i found that you could use NSArray not in a programatic way. I was thinking, great, i can make sets of uiviews into an NSArray and then get a proper outlet in xcode and retreiving all my uiviews from the NSArray.

The fact is when i put a NSArray into the nib file, i can't do nothing into it's property list. So the fact is i don't use the NSArray the correct way it should be. So is there anyone who could explain me how can i use my nsArray the way i want to? This will explain me why using non-display class into the nib file, and the purpose of it.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you might be confusing `NSArray` with `NSArrayController`.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* instantiate an `NSArray` instance in a nib file using the "Object" item in the IB library...but you probably don't want to.

Comment: Yeah, too bad IB can't provide into the xml some custom data for NSArray for example. Still i just don't get it for all the classes you can get from a nib file if this is just to make them into delegates object. I mean this can be made from xcode as easy they're made in IB.